# How do I fix the error "couldn't find a place to store the pinned certificate"

Tags: pantheon-mail, release-hera

Trying Elementary Hera - ran the email program, was told my mail server certificate was untrusted, got prompted to trust it, when I did so, there was a long delay after which the error

Couldn't find a place to store the pinned certificate

was displayed.

How can I fix this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This code in Terminal should fix it:

```
$ mkdir -p ~/.config/pkcs11/modules
$ curl https://gitlab.gnome.org/GNOME/gnome-keyring/raw/ff229abca62db366c84dfe58035324f6d8ca6059/pkcs11/rpc-layer/gnome-keyring.module.in > ~/.config/pkcs11/modules/gnome-keyring.module
```

https://bugzilla.gnome.org/show_bug.cgi?id=736640#c27

Answer (score 0):

This is a known issue with the older version of Geary that Mail is based on.
The newer Geary has fixed this.

References:

https://gitlab.gnome.org/GNOME/geary/-/issues/20
https://bugzilla.gnome.org/show_bug.cgi?id=736640#c27

The second link provides a temporary workaround.

-Reed