# Protonmail account never properly loads

Tags: pantheon-mail

I'm using a ProtonMail account with Mail. The 'loading' indicator never stops spinning. Eventually, messages load in the left pane, but never seem to load in the right pane.

Answer (score 0):

I'm also using the proton-bridge.
You might want to check this out:

[How do I fix the error "couldn't find a place to store the pinned certificate"](https://elementaryos.stackexchange.com/questions/21387/how-do-i-fix-the-error-couldnt-find-a-place-to-store-the-pinned-certificate)